# Rails - Rendering different "dashboard/user profile" depending on the type of user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

My app has different user types/model, ex: Doctor and MedicalInstitution (not sure if those are good names btw). They have polymorphic association to User.

The controllers so far:

HomesController - Verify if user is logged in or not. If yes redirect to dashboard_path if not redirect to landing page.

DashboardsController - "Display the current user profile." Code:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def show
    @user = current_user.profile
    render "#{@user.dashboard_something_variable}_dashboard"
  end
end
```

Is this a good idea, or would you split the controllers? I feel that DoctorsController's show action would be for other people to view radiologist profiles, not for the Doctor himself to view his profile/private things.

Thank you!

Comment: How much content is to be different per user type? That would help for a better answer.

Comment: The Institutions post jobs which the Doctors can perform. I guess you can say it's "e-commerce for doctors". So there are shared parts (name, edit profile link, etc..) and not so shared parts (post job, answer job...). What do you think?

Comment: I am thinking you should have layout partials for each user type. Then render them based on user type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a partial for each view..

```
def show
  # ...
  @partial = current_user.profile # 'doctor', 'radiologist',...
end
```

In show.html.erb:

```
<%= render @partial %>
```

Then you would save each view partial in the controller's views folder, e.g. `_doctor.html.erb`, `_radiologist.html.erb`.

Comment: What's the difference in rendering inside `show.html.erb` and in the controller? Is it to have "a shared layout"?

Comment: For me it's just cleaner. The comon stuff would be in `show.html.erb` and the unique things could go in the partial.